# Configuring PHP with MySQL and Apache

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am trying to configure MySQL to be used with PHP and Apache. But getting the following error. I am not sure what to do.

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()`

Please explain what are steps to configure MySQL with PHP and Apache. What changes are required in the `.ini` and `.dll` files.

I am using the following versions:

- Apache: 2.2.19
- PHP: 5.3.8
- MySQL: 5.5.15

I am using Windows machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In php.ini, uncomment the line:
`;extension=php_mysql.dll`

Answer (score 0):

have you got install the mysql extension for php?

Comment: No I didn't install mysql extension for PHP.

Comment: you mean the DLL files in PHP extension directory? If yes then I have those DLL files.

Comment: `phpinfo()` showing one table with heading `mysqlnd`. There is no other table related to MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not exactly the answer you're looking for but have you considered using XAMPP? It's an installer for that exact setup (apache + php + mysql).

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have used XAMPP earlier but right now I want to use Apache only.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using windows, I recommend using WAMP to set up your server -  http://www.wampserver.com/en/.

Much quicker than fighting this kinda battle yourself.

FWIW, look in (I think) PHP.ini; there's a long list of libraries which are all commented out by default. MySQL support is one of them; uncomment, restart apache, try again. The names are fairly obvious, though from memory there are 2 MySQL ones.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link with every explanation: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/php_mysql_win.html